# How to change the way split returns values in R?

Tags: r, split

I'm working on a project and I want to take a matrix, split it by the values w and x, and then for each of those splits find the maximum value of y.
Here's an example matrix

```
>rah = cbind(w = 1:6, x = 1:3, y = 12:1, z = 1:12)
 >rah
      w x  y  z
 [1,] 1 1 12  1
 [2,] 2 2 11  2
 [3,] 3 3 10  3
 [4,] 4 1  9  4
 [5,] 5 2  8  5
 [6,] 6 3  7  6
 [7,] 1 1  6  7
 [8,] 2 2  5  8
 [9,] 3 3  4  9
[10,] 4 1  3 10
[11,] 5 2  2 11
[12,] 6 3  1 12
```

So I run split

```
> doh = split(rah, list(rah[,1], rah[,2]))
> doh
$`1.1`
[1]  1  1  1  1 12  6  1  7

$`2.1`
integer(0)

$`3.1`
integer(0)

$`4.1`
[1]  4  4  1  1  9  3  4 10

$`5.1`
integer(0)

$`6.1`
integer(0)

$`1.2`
integer(0)

$`2.2`
[1]  2  2  2  2 11  5  2  8

$`3.2`
integer(0)

$`4.2`
integer(0)

$`5.2`
[1]  5  5  2  2  8  2  5 11
...
```

So I'm a bit confused as to how take the output of split and use it to sort the rows with the matching combination of w and x values (Such as row 1 compared to row 7) and then compared them to find the one with the high y value.

EDIT: Informative answers so far but I just realized that I forgot to mention one very important part: I want to keep the whole row (x,w,y,z).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aggregate` instead

```
> aggregate(y ~ w + x, max, data=rah)
  w x  y
1 1 1 12
2 4 1  9
3 2 2 11
4 5 2  8
5 3 3 10
6 6 3  7
```

If you want to use `split`, try

```
> split_rah <- split(rah[,"y"], list(rah[, "w"], rah[, "x"]))
> ind <- sapply(split_rah, function(x) length(x)>0)
> sapply(split_rah[ind], max)
1.1 4.1 2.2 5.2 3.3 6.3 
 12   9  11   8  10   7
```

Just for the record, `summaryBy` from doBy package also works in the same fashion of `aggregate`

```
> library(doBy)
> summaryBy(y ~ w + x, FUN=max, data=as.data.frame(rah))
  w x y.max
1 1 1    12
2 2 2    11
3 3 3    10
4 4 1     9
5 5 2     8
6 6 3     7
```

data.table solution:

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(rah)
> dt[, max(y), by=list(w, x)]
   w x V1
1: 1 1 12
2: 2 2 11
3: 3 3 10
4: 4 1  9
5: 5 2  8
6: 6 3  7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> tapply(rah[,"y"], list( rah[,"w"], rah[,"x"]), max)
   1  2  3
1 12 NA NA
2 NA 11 NA
3 NA NA 10
4  9 NA NA
5 NA  8 NA
6 NA NA  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `plyr` package:

```
ddply(as.data.frame(rah),.(w,x),summarize,z=max(y))
  w x  z
1 1 1 12
2 2 2 11
3 3 3 10
4 4 1  9
5 5 2  8
6 6 3  7
```